# problemas de la carga de la web

Tags: wordpress, configuración, puertos

tengo una pagina web en wordpress y al configurar el puerto me sale incompleta la pagina 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi aparece cuando esta por el puerto 80, pero si lo coloco por el puerto 8080 me agarra bien, por que sera esto?

Comment: Mira la consola a ver que errores te está generando, puede ser la ruta, permisos de ficheros, restricciones de seguridad y muchas otras cosas.

Comment: Buenas es correcto, era las rutas de la web use el plugins Better Search Replace para reemplasarlos y ya cargo bien la pagina . gracias

Answer (score 0):

Son tus hojas de estilo que no están cargando bien.

Puede ser que las rutas que hacen referencia a las mismas esten mal o sino la caché que tiene hojas de estilo antiguas.

Abrí la página y apretá CTRL + SHIFT + R para hacer un clear de la cache, debería volver a cargar todo.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Revisa en que carpeta de tu servidor tiene las hojas de estilo, asegúrate de que las tienes en la carpeta de tu página web y que le estas dando la ruta correcta de acuerdo a la carpeta de tu servidor.